# Reporting Services Rendering error on ASP.NET Page

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, reporting-services

I am trying to display reporting service elements in a web page as little 'widget' like elements, where when you click on one of the elements it takes you to the reporting services page that holds all of the data.

This works on my machine, and when run on two other machines, however, it is not working on the development server or another developer's machine.

It works in dev in Google chrome, but not in IE 7 or 8.  The images/links work if you right click on them and select "open link", but they are not click-able as links, which pisses the business unit off.

I would really appreciate some help on this.  Here is the information pertinent to what I am trying to do.  URLs and such changed for obvious purposes.

- .NET 3.5
  = IIS 7

This is the ASPX element as added on the page.

```
    <div style="width: 411px; float: left;">
       <a href="RenderReport.aspx/myreport.pdf" style="text-decoration: none;">
           <rsweb:ReportViewer ID="rptVwOriginatedFallout" runat="server" Font-Names="Verdana"
               Font-Size="8pt" InteractiveDeviceInfos="(Collection)" ProcessingMode="Remote"
               WaitMessageFont-Names="Verdana" WaitMessageFont-Size="14pt" ShowToolBar="False"
               Height="260px" SizeToReportContent="True" BorderStyle="None">
               <ServerReport ReportPath="/MyReport" ReportServerUrl="http://reportingserver/" />
           </rsweb:ReportViewer>
       </a>
   </div>
```

At the top of the page I have:

```
<%@ Register Assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"
Namespace="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms" TagPrefix="rsweb" %>
```

In the web.config under assemblies I have:

```
<add assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
<add assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
```

Under the httpHandlers I have:

```
<add path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" verb="*" type = "Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" validate="false" />
```

I have tried placing the appropriate information under  and running it in Integrated mode as well on the server, but that did not work either.

Answer (score -1):

I think you need to look at what html is generated. It may be the html is wacky enough to throw the browsers off. You may need to change the way you link it. Ie. remove the anchor tag & add a onclick javascript method to the outer div. couple that with changing the mouse cursor with css, it'll look like a link still.

Simon